# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to

Tags: android

Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "f6d49cf60f195ef2a8727d6130b914dcf0bccbc6"

Answer (score 9):

Use latest version of Android gradle plugin (you've probably been using 1.4.0-beta6 so far):

#### *project* build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: @zhourihu On stackoverflow we dont thank. We upvote and accept answers.